# how can i hide text after any click on button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I hide text after two click on text in jQuery?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("p").click(function(){
                    $(this).hide("slow");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean double click?

Comment: are you looking for **[`.dblclick()`](https://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)** (double-click)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code for double click event.**

```js
$("p").dblclick(function(){
    $(this).hide("slow");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
```

**Code for second click event.**

```js
$("p").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('one'))
        $(this).hide('slow');
    else
        $(this).addClass("one");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
```